# Why a comma is getting printed in the beginning when we print a arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I wanted to print a array List in java but why a comma is getting printed in the beginning?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String name;
    List<String> nameList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        name=sc.nextLine();
        nameList.add(name);
    }
    System.out.println(nameList);
}

And this is the result i got

2
ABC
XYZ
[, ABC, XYZ]
```

As you can see why a comma is printed before ABC?

Comment: you should check it before add to list. since after inserting number you hit Enter.`name = sc.nextLine();
if (!name.equals(""))
 nameList.add(name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the soultion...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String name;
   List<String> nameList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        name=sc.nextLine();
        nameList.add(name);
    }
    System.out.println(nameList);
}
```

All you need to do is to add a `sc.nextLine();`  in order to clean after the int. Because without it the int gets into the ArrayList and this is why there is a `,` at the start. I hope you understand me.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks MC Star...now it is working as expected but can you explain me a little bit in depth as why int gets into arrayList??is that a bug??I dont get it..Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

nextInteger does not consume the newline characters. Therefore a nextLine is needed before the loop so that you read new full line in every iteration of the whole loop